# Recursing multiple lists of lists

Tags: prolog

Suppose we have a list like: `[[[[a],b,c],a,b,[a,b]]]`

I want to recurse down the list an get `[[a],b,c]` or `[a]` for instance.

Doing something like this: `listsplit([H|T], H, T).` when returning head I only get to one level of the list. I tried recursively doing it but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep in mind that [H|T] is just syntactic sugar: lists are just binary trees with the head-branch always being a leaf. So you can deconstruct it just like any other tree:

```
| ?- X = [[[[a],b,c],a,b,[a,b]]], X = [[Y|_]|_], X = [[[Z|_]|_]|_].
```

This results in:

```
X = [[[[a],b,c],a,b,[a,b]]]
Y = [[a],b,c]
Z = [a]
```

However, this "smells". What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there are better ways then representing trees by awkwardly nested lists?

Comment: I am in the midst of writing a small interpreter where I'm creating a symbol table in prolog. The structure of my input is something like this `[[function1],[[function2],[[function3]]]` and I'm trying to deconstruct it in order to store the parameters inside the functions (return value, input parameters, function body etc.) . An example of a function is: `[[int,[add]],[ (],[[int,[a]],[[,],[[int,[b]],[]]]],[)],[=],[[[a],[]],[[+],[[b],[]]]]]`

Comment: This thing does not at all look like a symbol table. Symbol table is essentially something like a big hash that maps identifiers to the corresponding semantic constructs in the current scope. What you got here has all kind of lexical junk in it, like commas and parentheses. It's at least two levels before the semantic analysis. Trying to make lexing/parsing/semantic analysis at once using nested lists as the only data structure will not be very fun. I propose you separate the steps more cleanly, and design appropriate data structures first.